# Reading Text file line by line and storing it in array

Tags: c++, arrays

The Problem is ,only the last word in the text file is being alloted all the positions of the array.  pls help

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int i;
string a[200000];
string b[1];
char str;
void store()
{

    ifstream file("english3.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        while(getline(file,line))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < =200000; i++)
            {
                file >> a[200000];
            }
        }
        cout<<"The dic words are:"<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
        {
            cout<<" "<<a[200000];
        }        
    }

}
    
int main()
{
    store();
}
```

and also please tel how to compare a string (word) from user to this array.

Comment: Please indent the code properly and explain what that gobledy-gook does!

Comment: What do you expect this line: `cout<<" "<<a[200000];` to do? If you explain that with your own words, you'll probably see why it's not doing what you think...

Comment: And I am surprised the code is not causing overflow!!

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Not all "overflows" are detected

Comment: And again.. What do you expect this line: `file >> a[200000];` to do? And why is placed in the body of a `while` statement

Comment: You should really try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: i am trying to stor all the words of a text file into an array.And storing a word into different array(given by user). And comparing those two arrays.

Comment: @BhavaniShankar Go through your code and next to each line write a comment telling what the code line is supposed to do. Example: `for(int i = 0; i < =200000; i++)   // Loop 200000 times` You'll most like find some code lines that you can't even explain to yourself - and that's where you have the bug.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a Plain-Old-Array of `std::string` instead of `std::vector<std::string>`? An array of 200000 `std::string` may well exhaust your stack space leading to StackOverflow (well, I guess you are already here...).

Comment: I think you need to return to the introduction to arrays in your book and read more carefully about indexing.

Answer (score 1):

First, this line

```
file >> a[200000];
```

always writes into `a[200000]` (and this is undefined behavior due to overflowing).

Not all overflows are detected. Since overflowing is an *undefined hehavior*, anything could happen if you do so, and of course "anything" includes the case "everything looks fine, without crashing or bogus result". If you're familiar with operating system or assembly language or some other low level skills, you'll know why. However, there are still ways for detecting such problem.

---

Secondly, you should correctly use the result of `getline`

```
getline(file,line)
```

This function reads from file line by line, and **stores the result into `line`**.

---

Obviously you did not learn C++ well. Variables `b`, `i` and `str` declared as global are not used; `iostream` does not require `stdio.h`; poor indents; incorrect use of array, ... I (personally) strongly suggest you go over C++ basics before going on writing programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector instead, why wouldn't you right?

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

vector <string> v;
ifstream file( path );
if( file.is_open( ) ){
    string line;
    while( getline( file, line ) ){
        v.push_back( line );
    }
}
```

Comment: what happened to `std::`? I think you forgot to write it :) Rest in nice

Comment: I agree with @4386427. clearing an empty vector... That's unecessary

Comment: That is a copy paste from my code, I am actually passing a vector to function by reference. Thanks for the heads up.